# Concurrent read access on map structure without lock

Tags: java, multithreading, hashmap, linkedhashmap

I have a hashmap:

```
LinkedHashMap<Long, List<IOperation>> operations.
```

Which is written at by multiple threads. I use a lock around it.

```
synchronized (lock){...}
```

To make sure that only 1 thread writes on it at a given moment.

Neveretheless, in some occasions I need to operate some long read requests on it.

For this purpose I copy the map:

```
temp.putAll(operations);
```

or

```
= new LinkedHashMap<>(operations)
```

Is there a way to make such a copy with the following premises:

- No need to lock the map to copy it.
- No call by value on the members of the map and its copy.

Thanks already

Some additional details.

I execute quite often some series of long reads on it and performance is crucial.

Comment: Basically, no, you have to take that `lock` for any operations at all, especially those you listed above.  Anything else risks `ConcurrentModificationException` or worse.

Answer (score 0):

It would most likely be easier for you when initializing your `LinkedHashMap<Long, List<IOperation>>` to wrap it in `Collections#synchronizedMap` so each atomic operation on the map will be synchronized, rather than having to do it yourself.

If you insist on copying the `Map` without having to lock it, I would just create another `LinkedHashMap` with the synchronized `Map` when beginning to read it.

```
Map<Long, List<IOperation>> copy = new LinkedHashMap<>(synchronizedMap);
```

You can also eliminate the need for the copy of the `Map` by simply wrapping the "long read requests" in a synchronized block using the `Map` as the lock.

Comment: but is synchronizedMap ordered by the insertition order?

Comment: and doesn't synchronizedMap come with an overhead for normal case operations as well?

Comment: As long as the `Map` that you're using is a `LinkedHashMap`, then the `Map` will be ordered by insertion.  There is overhead when synchronizing anything, but the JVM can account for that by optimizing locks based on usage.

Comment: If I copy the map, the values are still connected? (The references stay the same?)

Comment: That's why I recommend not copying the map, as every reference will have to be deep copied (you'll have to implement that).

Comment: I'm quite concerned about the performance since I have a few thousand of operations entering that map.
And I'm doing a huge amount of reads on it (like 100* more reading than writing)

Comment: I think https://github.com/ben-manes/caffeine might be an option for me.

Comment: https://github.com/Raycoms/thesis/blob/working/src/main/java/main/java/com/bag/server/AbstractRecoverable.java

Is the class and the two maps I have to check